# Organize data from table based in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table like this and i need to split it to analise the data better

```
ID | doc | name    | price | pay 
1  | doc1| PERSON1 | 1     | 1
2  | doc2| PERSON1 | 10    | 0
3  | doc3| PERSON2 | 12    | 1
4  | doc4| PERSON2 | 1     | 0
5  | doc5| PERSON2 | 15    | 0
6  | doc6| PERSON3 | 2     | 1
7  | doc7| PERSON3 | 23    | 0
8  | doc8| PERSON3 | 3     | 0
9  | doc9| PERSON4 | 8     | 0
```

and i need an output like this and i don't know how to do it!

```
 name         | price | pay 
 PERSON1      |       | 
 Doc1         | 1     | 1
 Doc2         | 10    | 0
 Total payed  | 1     |
 Total per pay| 10    | 
 Total        | 11    |
 PERSON2      |       | 
 Doc3         | 12    | 1
 Doc4         | 1     | 0
 Doc5         | 15    | 0
 Total payed  | 12    | 
 Total per pay| 16    | 
 Total        | 28    |
 PERSON3      |       | 
 Doc6         | 2     | 1
 Doc7         | 23    | 0
 Doc8         | 3     | 0
 Total payed  | 2     | 
 Total per pay| 26    | 
 Total        | 28    |
 PERSON4      |       | 
 Doc9         | 8     | 0
 Total payed  | 0     | 
 Total per pay| 8     | 
 Total        | 8     |
 Payed        | 15    |
 PER PAY      | 60    |
 Total SUM    | 75    |
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: you must write a stored procedure

Comment: You might pull this off with the `UNPIVOT` operator. You will have to unpivot twice though, and might need dynamic SQL if the persons and documents are not known beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't fathom how you are analyzing the data if the second format is better.  You can do this, but it is painful:

```
select doc, price, pay
from ((select doc, price, pay, 2 as ord, name
       from t
      ) union all
      (select distinct name as doc, null, null, 1, name
       from t
       group by name
      ) union all
      (select 'total paid', sum(pay * price), null, 3, name
       from t
       group by name
      ) union all
      (select 'total not paid', sum( (1 - pay) * price), null, 3, name
       from t
       group by name
      ) union all
      (select 'total', sum(pay), null, 5, name
       from t
       group by name
      )
     ) t
order by name, ord;
```

Comment: The  `(1 - pay) * price` is very nice trick to simplify the logic and alternative of case/iif

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[doc] VARCHAR(24)
   ,[name] VARCHAR(24)
   ,[price] INT
   ,[pay] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [doc], [name], [price], [pay])
VALUES (1, 'doc1', 'PERSON1', 1, 1)
      ,(2, 'doc2', 'PERSON1', 10, 0)
      ,(3, 'doc3', 'PERSON2', 12, 1)
      ,(4, 'doc4', 'PERSON2', 1, 0)
      ,(5, 'doc5', 'PERSON2', 15, 0)
      ,(6, 'doc6', 'PERSON3', 2, 1)
      ,(7, 'doc7', 'PERSON3', 23, 0)
      ,(8, 'doc8', 'PERSON3', 3, 0)
      ,(9, 'doc9', 'PERSON4', 8, 0);

SELECT MIN([ID]) OVER (PARTITION BY [name]) AS [ID]
      ,[ID] AS [IternalID]
      ,[doc]
      ,[price]
      ,[pay]
FROM @DataSource
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN([ID])
      ,0
      ,[name]
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
FROM @DataSource
GROUP BY [name]
UNION ALL
SELECT [ID]
      ,CASE [column]
            WHEN 'Total payed' THEN 997
            WHEN 'Total per pay' THEN 998
            WHEN 'Total' THEN 999
        END
      ,[column]
      ,[value]
      ,NULL
FROM
(
    SELECT IIF([name] IS NULL, 1000, MIN([ID]))
          ,[name]
          ,SUM(IIF([pay] = 1, [Price], 0))
          ,SUM(IIF([pay] = 1, 0, [Price]))
          ,SUM([Price])
    FROM @DataSource
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
    (
        [name]
       ,()
    )
) DS ([ID], [name], [Total payed], [Total per pay], [Total])
UNPIVOT
(
    [value] FOR [column] IN ([Total payed], [Total per pay], [Total])
) UNPVT
ORDER BY [ID]
        ,[IternalID];
```

It s a full working example that can give you the output. You can change it a little bit to match your real data.